# How to execute a function from a Python script (with parameters) in PHP?

Tags: php, python, external-script

I've recently been working on a web crawler with PHP and as a newish PHP coder, I'm not the most advanced. I also know a decent bit of Python and there are a few things I am able to do in Python yet not in PHP.

Is there any way for me to run a Python function with parameters inside a PHP script? Please be specific in your answers as I'm not amazing at PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Run the Python script using php's [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function

Think of `shell_exec` as basically running commands in your terminal. So if you normally run your python script from the shell like this:

```
/python-scripts/myscript.py "here is an argument"
```

You would pass the same command into `shell_exec`, like this:

```
$output = shell_exec("python-scripts/myscript.py 'here is an argument'");
```

Note: `shell_exec` will return the output of the command you run, so save it to a variable if you want to use the output from the python program in your PHP script.

**Edits:** fixed syntax issues, provided a more specific example

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php you can search you know.

Comment: I saw that and I am still unsure. Do you first have to import the program and also how do you use parameters in the function? DO you just call them as normal?

Comment: see how python arguments are passed in a program.

Comment: When I try to run my script from terminal it says No Such File or Directory Found, even though I checked and I used the correct command and its in the correct directory.

Comment: Make sure to use an absolute path (i.e. `/python-scripts/myscript.py` instead of `python-scripts/mysript.py`) - note the `/` at the beginning of the absolute path, since it is relative to the root directory. But if you are getting the "No Such File or Directory Found", you definitely aren't pointing to the file you think you are

Comment: It worked and I got rid of that Error yet now I have Permission denied. I checked the Sharing and Permissions and I  am able to Read and Write to the document but I am not able to open it in terminal

Comment: I hope you accept my answer after all this help :) Try changing the permissions on the file: `chmod +x yourscript.py`. You may also be getting a permission denied because you are trying to read/write a file in your script. In that case, you need to change the permissions on those files as well using `chmod` from the shell

Comment: It worked in terminal yet doesn't work in PHP....