# Calling a function of a Python Script from PHP

Tags: php, python

I have Python script with a fucntion. I want to call this function from PHP while passing two parameters to the function.
What am i doing wrong here? :/

## myscript.py

```
def InitPython(ID,Name):
      'DO STUFF'
```

## PHP

```
 $varone='bleh';
    $vartwo='blah';
    $output = shell_exec("myscript.py '$varone' 'vartwo' ");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689725/how-to-execute-a-function-from-a-python-script-with-parameters-in-php

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could answer my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP**:

It could be possible that your `myscript.py` is not found, use a Full Path:

```
 $output = shell_exec("<your Full Path>myscript.py '$varone' 'vartwo' ");
```

**myscript.py**

You must **Read** the passed Parameters in your Python Script, for instance:

```
def InitPython(ID,Name):
  'DO STUFF'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import sys
   InitPython(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

> Relevant: Python Documentation: [module-argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)
>
> The argparse module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line interfaces. The program defines what arguments it requires, and argparse will figure out how to parse those out of sys.argv

Comment: Awesome! Works Perfectly